VSCodeのRemote SSHを終了しても、サーバ側のプロセスが終了しない
標題の件ですが、VSCodeでリモートssh編集をしています。
VSCodeを終了すると、サーバ側で実行されているvscode-serverも終了すると思うのですが、終了せず、気がつかずに、次にVSCodeを立ち上げると、さらに新しいプロセスがサーバー側で走り、そのうちパンクします。
これは、似たようなCursor IDEでも同様の動作になります。ここ一ヵ月位で起こり始めた現象だと思うのですが、何か情報をお持ちであれば、教えてください。

サーバー側も同時に終了するというのは誤解かもしれません。接続が切断された後デフォルトで8時間はサーバープロセスは生きているようです。ssh process doesn't terminate after remote-ssh disconnected #6727, Configurable Remote SSH Server Timeout #440 Windows11のCopilot(プレビュー版)でリモ－トVSCodeでSSHセッションが終了した時にVSCodeサーバーを終了させる設定を出来ますか？等と問い合わせると、「Remote.SSH: Server Install Path」や「Remote.SSH: Server Data Path」にSSH接続の終了時にサーバーを停止するスクリプトを追加する方法を答えてくれました。ご自分で確かめてみてください。

8時間生きている！　了解です。ありがとうございます。

追記します。
設定->拡張機能->Remote.SSH:Use Exec Server のチェックを外す。　（サーバーに接続するときに新しいブーストラップモードを使用します。接続の問題が発生した場合にオフに切り替えることができます。）
ここをOFFにすると、とりあえずサーバ側のプロセスは終了しました。
copailotは正しい方法では無いが、終了する可能性があるとの返事でした。
